# pf shortcuts for block quick

Tags: pf, bsd

Looking at https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/shortcuts.html it's not clear to me if these are the same-

```
block quick from <bruteforce>
```

and-

```
block in quick from <bruteforce> to any
block out quick from any to <bruteforce>
```

similarly, I wonder if this is also equivalent-

```
block quick <bruteforce>
```

(My goal here is to block any access, in or out, from the IPs listed in the  table.)

Comment: LOL someone downvoted my question.

Comment: if you didn't know already, `pfctl -s rules` is handy to print the rules as-interpreted by pf

Answer (score 1):

They are not. To be short, only two rules in the middle are valid, others are just a noise. `from` requires a pair of addresses and a `to` keyword, and the last rule is just a total nonense.

Comment: The first form is valid on openbsd - `from` & `to` are each optional (default to `any`) - the rule is interpreted as `block quick from <bruteforce> to any`, which _is_ equivalent to the two middle rules together

Answer (score 0):

Although with Pf some keywords could be redundant and thus allowed to be omitted the last rule is a total no-go. You can refer to `man pf.conf` which has its syntax rules outlined with BNF-like grammar description.